# Update a column not working

Tags: sql, plsql, toad

I am trying to execute below query in toad.

```
UPDATE rd_catg_sync_tables
SET RCST_SYNC_COL2='Insert into ASM_ACE_SERVICE
(SERVICE_ID, SERVICE_NAME, SERVICE_DESC, SERVICE_LEVEL, SERVICE_CODE, SERVICE_CREATED_DATE, SERVICE_TYPE,        SERVICE_REF_TBL,ASM_SC_CATGID,ASM_SC_MODIFIED_BY)
Values
(?, '?', '?', ?, '?', TO_DATE('?', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), '?',    '?','?','?');'
WHERE RCST_TABLE_NAME=ASM_ACE_SERVICE
```

But when I run it's asking values for `MI:SS`. But it's a part of data which I need to insert into the RCST_SYNC_COL2. Kindly someone help me how to insert this data into that coloumn.

Comment: what exactly do u want to update ? the whole table or some specific column's of the table ?

Comment: I want set RCST_SYNC_COL2 to the below value  
'Insert into ASM_ACE_SERVICE
(SERVICE_ID, SERVICE_NAME, SERVICE_DESC, SERVICE_LEVEL, SERVICE_CODE, SERVICE_CREATED_DATE, SERVICE_TYPE,        SERVICE_REF_TBL,ASM_SC_CATGID,ASM_SC_MODIFIED_BY)
Values
(?, '?', '?', ?, '?', TO_DATE('?', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), '?',    '?','?','?');

Answer (score 1):

You need additional quoting.  To escape a single quote in SQL, use two single quotes in a row:

```
update rd_catg_sync_tables
    set RCST_SYNC_COL2 = '
Insert into ASM_ACE_SERVICE(SERVICE_ID, SERVICE_NAME, SERVICE_DESC, SERVICE_LEVEL, SERVICE_CODE, SERVICE_CREATED_DATE, SERVICE_TYPE, SERVICE_REF_TBL,ASM_SC_CATGID,ASM_SC_MODIFIED_BY)
    Values
(?, ''?'', ''?'', ?, ''?'', TO_DATE(''?'', ''MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS''), ''?'', ''?'',''?'',''?'');'
    where RCST_TABLE_NAME = 'ASM_ACE_SERVICE'
```

I don't know how you are going to execute the subquery, but the single quotes around the place holders (`?`) and the semicolon at the end are probably unnecessary.

Comment: Hi I made the above changes and executed it..It threw below error.  

 ORA-00904: "ASM_ACE_SERVICE": invalid identifier

Comment: where RCST_TABLE_NAME = 'ASM_ACE_SERVICE'